# Derivative of inverse trigonometric functions: $f(x)=\arcsin\left(2x\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, inverse-function

While trying to find the derivative of 
$$f(x)=\arcsin\left(2x\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)$$
we arrive at two different answers by substituting $x=\sin t$ or $x=\cos t$. The aim is to simplify it as $\arcsin(\sin2t)$ and further simplify it as $2t$ and take its derivative. Proceeding in that manner, I arrived at two different answers for the derivative. I could understand that it was because the function $f$ is defined differently in different intervals, and as I have solved the problem without considering the intervals, I hit this answer. Also, I thought that since $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ will coincide only when $t=\dfrac{\pi}4$, $x=\pm\dfrac1{\sqrt{2}}$ will be the points where the definition changes. I got some more clarity when I looked at the graph of $f(x)$ but I could not figure out a way to systematically figure out what answer suits what interval.

MAJOR EDIT:  I made a mistake in the function itself that I had given. My question earlier read:
$$f(x)=\arcsin\left(2x\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)$$ 
But I wanted only for what I've now altered it as. My sincere apologies...

EDIT: My question is how to figure out the interval in which the substitution applies for such problems in general. I don't need the expression for the  derivative of  $f(x)$.

Note: I am new to this community, so please point out any deviation from the policy, if I have deviated.
Also, I couldn't post my working as I do not have $10$ reputation.

Comment: At least put each formula between dollars.

Comment: The [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) may help.

Comment: Thank you for the link... I've made the changes.

Comment: your substitution with $sin$ or $\cos$ doesn't work. $\sqrt{\sin^2x-1}=\sqrt{-\cos^2x}$ is undefined . . .

Comment: @user108128 could you please edit this comment? Because the last expression is unclear.

Comment: @user108128  also, I understood that my substitution doesn't work... Or rather it works within certain intervals. x=sint works with $[-1/√2,1/√2]$ and x=cost works within $[1/√2, 1]$. My question was, how to figure out the intervals for such problems

Comment: As deleted answer proposed, you may use $\cosh$ substitution. You can't work win $\sin$ or $\cos$ here at all.

Comment: @user108128  oh... Why does sin or cos substitution fail?

Comment: $x^2-1\geq0$ shows $|x|\geq1$ while $|\sin|\leq1$

Comment: You only ever get $\arcsin 2t$ if you actually had $f(x)=\arcsin (2x\sqrt{1-x^2})$. With $\arcsin(2x\sqrt{x^2-1})$ you get something resembling the duplication formula only with imaginary $x$. Therefore, hyperbolic substitutions.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thank you for pointing it out... That was what I intended. I've made the edit now

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\arcsin(2x\sqrt{x^2-1})$$
$$\sin(f(x))=2x\sqrt{x^2-1}$$
$$f'(x)\ \cos(f(x))=2\sqrt{x^2-1}+2x\dfrac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$
$$f'(x)\sqrt{1-\sin^2f(x)}=2\dfrac{2x^2-1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$
$$f'(x)=2\dfrac{2x^2-1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}\sqrt{1-4x^4+4x^2}}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But my question was about the answer I got in a certain method. It would be of great help if you could clarify that question

Comment: Really I couldn't read your post. Now you've edited so I read it!

Comment: oh yes. And thanks for your suggestion in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

$$ f(x) = arcsin(2x\sqrt{x^2-1}) $$

Replace x=cosh$\theta$

then f(x) = arcsin(sinh$2\theta$)

by differentiating f(x),

f '(x) = $\frac{2cosh(2\theta)}{\sqrt{1-sinh^2(2\theta)}\sqrt{x^2-1}}$

Replacing $ cosh(2\theta) = 2x^2-1 $

f '(x) = $\frac{4x^2-2}{\sqrt{1-4x^4+4x^2}\sqrt{x^2-1}}$

Comment: Is x=sinhθ a valid substitution?

Comment: @RaghavasimhanVaradharajan, x = $ cosh(\theta) $ is a valid substitution